# What is "Nächstvergangenheit"?

Tags: meaning

My Hungarian/German edition of Bartók's [*Mikrokozmosz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikrokosmos_(Bart%C3%B3k)) contains the following footnote (emphasis mine):

> Um — im Gegensatz zur in der **Nächstvergangenheit** verbreiteten Auffassung — auf die Ausdrucksmöglichkeit der Musik hinzuweisen, haben wir den frage- bzw. antwortartigen Melodieteilen "fragende" und "antwortende" Verse unterlegt.

I'm a native German speaker, but I've never before encountered the word "Nächstvergangenheit". Google returns [very few results](https://www.google.com/search?q="n%C3%A4chstvergangenheit") for the term. Among them is the [*Ungarische Revue*](http://www.archive.org/stream/ungarischerevue00akadgoog/ungarischerevue00akadgoog_djvu.txt), which includes the following (emphasis mine):

> [...] denn die geringste derartige Erscheinung berührt alle jene 
>   unangenehm, die sich der schweren Stunden der **Nächstvergangenheit** 
>   und der Hauptursache der kaum behobenen Uebel noch zu erinnern vermögen.

Another Google result is the [table of contents](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiLjr_LzabdAhWFjKQKHVmrBiwQFjABegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fd-nb.info%2F451832949%2F04&usg=AOvVaw3k0ql4e9lwOSDXHywPJhVX) for a [music history book](https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=idn%3D451832949), including the following entry (emphasis mine, I don't have access to the book itself):

> Eszterhäza in der **Nächstvergangenheit** und in der Gegenwart

[Esterhäza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eszterh%C3%A1za) is a palace in Hungary.

So it seems that "Nächstvergangenheit" is the name for a historical period or event, probably related to Hungary. Does anyone know more?

Comment: There is no `hungarian` tag, and I don't have enough reputation to create it. Feel free to add it.

Comment: wahrscheinlich die unmittelbar kürzlich gerade passierte Vergangenheit

Comment: @äüö: So you think this isn't a specific time in history, but simply the recent past relative to the time of writing? That does sound plausible, but makes me wonder why the only references to it I can find are all related to Hungary.

Comment: yes, I think so. Maybe it's a copy'n'paste issue in Hungary, or a direct word-by-word translation from Hungarian. Anyway, I seem to understand it but haven't heard that word at all until now.

Comment: „Nächstvergangenheit“ ist kein echtes deutsches Wort. Es wird auch nicht umgangssprachlich verwendet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked on Reddit about Hungarian words that might translate to "Nächstvergangenheit", and got [an answer from skp_005](https://www.reddit.com/r/hungary/comments/9djn5h/does_anyone_know_about_n%C3%A4chstvergangenheit/e5i03d1/):

> There is a word, "közelmúlt", which means 'near past' / 'recent', literal translation "közel + múlt" -- 'near + past', that may be it.

And indeed, "közelmult" does occur in the Hungarian version of the footnote at about the same position as "Nächstvergangenheit" does in the German one.

Langenscheidt's dictionary [translates "közelmúlt" as "jüngste Vergangenheit"](https://de.langenscheidt.com/ungarisch-deutsch/k%C3%B6zelm%C3%BAlt#k%C3%B6zelm%C3%BAlt).

So it does seem that "Nächstvergangenheit" really is a slightly-too-literal translation of "közelmúlt" that somehow got picked up by a few writers of Hungary-related topics.

Comment: Sehr gut. So wird's sein. (y)

Comment: Demnach ist die Antwort auf die Frage "Was ist 'Nächstvergangenheit'": **eine fürs Deutsche unüblich wörtliche Übertragung eines Begriffs aus dem Ungarischen.** Außer im Falle dass der Übersetzer hier aus dichterischen Gründen ganz bewusst einen Magyarismus einführen wollte, ist das wohl eher eine ungeschickte (da zu sehr am einzelnen Wort klebende) Übersetzung des ungarischen Originals. Unmarkiertes ("normales") und gutes Deutsch wäre, von ***jüngster Vergangenheit*** zu sprechen.

Answer (score 4):

Wir kennen für die Unterscheidung eines Abstands der Vergangenheit zu heute die

> jüngere Vergangenheit

oder

> neuere Zeit

die

> jüngste Vergangenheit

(für sehr kurze Abstände) und die

> neueste Zeit

für kurz zuvor geschehene Dinge.

Die

> fernere Vergangenheit

für größere Zeitabstände

Die *Nächstvergangenheit*, die du gefunden hast, scheint mir eine etwas zu wörtliche Übersetzung zu sein.

Answer (score -1):

In some perceived *Fernvergangenheit* I used to study history as one of my specialties, and I have never met "Nächstvergangenheit" as a technical term in that sector of humanities.

There are, however, other terms established in German historiography such as

> Frühe Neuzeit
>
> Spätmittelalter
>
> Hochmittelalter
>
> Jungsteinzeit
>
> Altsteinzeit
>
> Früheisenzeit
>
> Spätbronzezeit
>
> Vormoderne
>
> Postmoderne

and even the obscure

> Vormärz

I would therefore say that, as Florian Brucker suggested in his comment, *Nahvergangenheit* is indeed **"simply the recent past relative to the time of writing".**

There is, moreover, the peculiar (and potentially hard to translate) term of

> Zeitgeschichte

which refers to the history (or historiography) of the most recent of recent past times - almost the present but characteristically treated with the tools of the historian.